# Two sisters born on the same day

Tags: lateral-thinking, family

Two sisters were born on the same day in the same year, yet they aren't twins. None of their other sisters share the birthday. What's going on? Explain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Miss Danner and the Elmer Boys](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1987/miss-danner-and-the-elmer-boys)

Comment: Possible dup: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/the-twins-with-a-different-age

Comment: Not a duplicate of either

Comment: Basically if the intended answer is FreakyDan's answer it is a duplicate as Bozmans says.  If the intended answer relies on them not looking alike or a play on the word sister, it is not a duplicate. Should remain open (unless another reason is identified to close it).

Comment: @kaine I think he explicitly tried to avoid the answer in the first one with "None of their other sisters share the birthday".

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop I would agree that that is likely even if I only saw the question. This is despite the fact that they could easily be brother-sister-sister triplets or they could be born near midnight so one sister is special.  I meant, however, that as OP posted his own answer that is different, it isn't a duplicate and shouldn't be closed.

Comment: However, could it possibly be considered "too broad"?

Comment: I agree with it being far far too broad

Comment: They were both born on the same *day of the week* (different months), not necessarily the same date. I can't post this as an answer because the question is protected.

Comment: does something smell between them?

Comment: Voted to close as the question is too broad, they are too many possible answers (as you can see from the 13 already up)

Comment: they are adopted

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> The sisters are nuns. Their shared birthday is a coincidence.

Comment: lol genius. I'd never think of that...

Comment: Am I the only one bothered by somebody asking a question and then answering his or her own question 4 minutes later?

Comment: Answering your own question is acceptable on SE. Not so on the puzzling site? I like that he did because the OP can always be outvoted, like on the other sites, by a better answer because answers are all in competition.

Comment: @geoO but in Puzzling, there's usually not much that makes an answer distinct. Now nobody can give this answer without basically stealing, because it's only one or two sentences anyway! Instead of taking the same premise and explaining it better, other answers have to come up with new premises.

Comment: @Warlord099: Yes.

Comment: @geoO A key part of that was "4 minutes later". Answering it is one thing, but at least let others have a chance to answer it. Otherwise it seems like asking the question just to gain cheap rep.

Comment: Nice. I came up with sorority sisters, which I suppose is along the same lines.

Comment: @Warlord099 pardon me. I wanted to leave the puzzle to everyone, but it looked liked the post was going to be closed as a duplicate (of a different question with a different answer), so I hastily answered it myself.

Comment: Oddly enough I actually prefer @Gully's answer. I think it stems from the fact that they're not yet "Sisters" (in the covenant sense) when they're born, they're just girls. So it becomes a case of ambiguous wording, whereas the alternative answer is semantically correct as well as logically correct :)

Comment: I'm confused. "Answer your own question," is a checkmark available moment you click "ask a question." Stack Exchange is ultimately at making information available, even Q&A style not the reputation of members. Some people will simply ask and answer their own question. This is a feature, no? But their OWN answer is editable and downvotable. This is also a feature.

Answer (score 69):

> When you say "two sisters", one thinks it means "they are each other's sister". While it actually only means "each one has a sister/brother". So the easiest answer is "they are not in the same family"

Comment: This is exactly as true as Colonel Panic's answer. I actually like it better.

Answer (score 59):

> The two sisters aren't twins, they are either triplets (or greater) with the other triplet being a brother (or bothers if greater than triplets).

Comment: That's one G.Weinberg riddle !

Comment: Definitely the most reasonable answer here, and probably the intended solution.

Answer (score 28):

> Same father, different mother.

Comment: @ColonelPanic answer is better though.

Comment: These would be half-sisters, which technically is different to just "sisters"

Comment: @Joe Which is why ColonelPanic's answer is better.

Comment: this is what I thought of first, and this is the simplest most logical answer

Comment: The other way around is also possible. Turns out there even is a name for it: heteropaternal superfecundation

Comment: @Joe What if the mothers are identical twins?  Or one woman with a time machine?

Comment: @bcrist identical twin mothers are still different people, so still half-sisters. And I'm not even going to bother with the time machine idea... just no

Comment: @Joe Only because (despite having "gene" in the name) genealogy deals with social constructions rather than biology.  Genetically speaking, their mothers have the same genetic code, and thus it would be impossible to determine which sister came from which mother.  They would be exactly as similar as any other pair of brothers or sisters.

Comment: @bcrist *Genetically* it would be the same as the two having been born from the same mother, perhaps, but the two identical twin mothers are *separate human beings* so the offspring would only share *one* parent (the father).  Therefore, *half* sisters is correct.

Answer (score 18):

> they are step sisters. One is adopted into the family.

Answer (score 16):

> Two identical twin brothers marry two identical twin sisters.  They each have baby girls born on the dame year-month-date.  While we'd consider the girls cousins, they are genetically sisters.

Answer (score 14):

> Same day, same year but what about a different month? e.g. 1st January 2000 and 1st December 2000 (more than 9 months apart)

Comment: I think "same day" very strongly implies same calendar day, which includes the month. If your answer were true it'd be a cheap trick.

Comment: Alternatively,
Same day of the week. Both were born on a Monday. One on a Monday in December, one on a Monday in January.

Comment: A variant on this might involve time travel or time zones.

Answer (score 13):

> They have the same genetic parents but different surrogate mothers.

Answer (score 10):

> One or more has died, so you *could* say they WERE twins but not ARE twins.

Comment: +1 because this was my second thought, after the "not having the same parents" angle.

Answer (score 5):

> Having [sister companies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidiary) founded in the same day at the same is not unusual.

Answer (score 5):

It's very similar to Colonel Panic's answer:

> The two ladies are [nursing sisters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nursing_management#Charge_nurse); their shared birthday is a coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

In the same vein as Taemyr's answer, but reversed:

> TL;DR: One Mother, possibly Two Different Fathers
>  [Superfecundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfecundation): **Superfecundation** is the fertilization of two or more ova from the same cycle by sperm from separate acts of sexual intercourse. The term superfecundation is derived from fecund, meaning the ability to produce offspring.
>  **Heteropaternal superfecundation** occurs when two different males father fraternal twins.

Comment: those are still twins; doesn't count

Comment: @ratchetfreak is correct -- they are fraternal twins: "Fraternal (dizygotic) twins develop from two eggs fertilised by two sperm, and are no more alike than individual brothers or sisters (siblings) born at different times". Also, heteropaternal sisters would only be half-sisters.

Comment: There is another, rarer circumstance where two ova from *different* cycles are fertilized. I don't know if those are considered twins or not, though.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I think you are right, but... If two girls (from separate pregnancies) that have only one parent in common, are not sisters but only half-sisters, I wonder if two heteropaternal girls from the same dizygotic double pregnancy (conceived naturally with two men and one woman) are only half-twins, and not twins.